# shader coding: calculate screen coordinates of fragment

Tags: shaders, cg, fragment-shader

Good morning,
I'm new to shader coding and trying to implement some visual effects code in shaders using billboards. (Yes, I couldn't have picked anything harder to start with, but I'm lucky that way)

**Setup:**
I have rendered the full screen z depth to an array of floats in a previous pass.
In the fragment shader I need the scene depth where the rendered fragment is displayed (to see if it's occluded). I can use tex2d() to get the depth value if I have the screen coordinates of the point being rendered in the fragment shader.

**Question:**
In the fragment shader how do you calculate the screen coordinates of the pixel (in the range 0-1.0)?

Is the position passed to the fragment shader a pixel offset? If so, I guess it would be:
    float2( position.x / screen-width, position.y / screen-height )

Thanks for any help/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CG (as your tags indicate) supports the `WPOS` semantic in [some profiles](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/cg_3_1_0013.html), for example [this one](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/gp4fp.html). An input parameter bound to the `WPOS` semantic will get the window position (with the origin in the lower-left) of the fragment.

Other languages, like GLSL, have similar predefined uniforms or inputs (`gl_FragCoord` for example), although the specifics of their value ranges may vary.

Comment: Gah. Of course the profile I'm using is all "to-be-written"

Comment: Woot! The documentation on wpos is pretty thin. I passed in the inverse of the screen size to the shader to calculate the offset into the texture array like this:
  float Zs = tex2D( DepthTexture, float2( scr.x * iViewWidth, 1 - ( scr.y * iViewHeight ) ) );